# Can`t go through django initial page while starting project

Tags: python, django, project

I am beginner in django and generally in coding. Early i have started django projects but in a more complicated way
 and now I follow  very simple  instruction like this:

```
1.  mkdir projectname (wherever you want)
2.  cd dir projectname
3.  virtualenv .
4.  source bin/activate
5.  pip install django==1.8
6.  pip freeze (checking django version)
7.  django-admin.py startproject projectname
8.  cd projectname (and rename dir projectname in it for “src”)
9.  cd src
10. it is possible to run project now but you need to run migration first
11. python manage.py  migrate (db.sqlite3 will be created)

creating superuser:
12.python manage.py syncdb
13.python manage.py createsuperuser

creating apps
14.python manage.py startapp appname
```

and met unexpected problem.
The matter is that I can not move further  through django initial page (and admin page as well). Whatever I did (made views with "home", urls.py with proper path, reload page with cmd-R) I still saw this start page. It seems django take settings(or smth else) from other place on my mac. Perhaps my virtual environment not ''safe'' enough? I`m totally stuck so please if you realize what I told help me.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No! All is normal but while i`m creating real page i still see initial one.

Comment: Can you show me your views, urls and template file?

Comment: like this:
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', 'projectname.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

Comment: @avkpol can you show the `home` view ?

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
 return render(request,'home.html',{})

Comment: Have you tried using TemplateView.as_view?

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is that you haven't added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: added for sure, checked, while starting project django wrote down such string to settings automatically

Comment: seems I have found why issue appeared ! I started  to use Sublime3 and it not save edit results when you switch between windows like pycharm so any changes not reflected on browser screen. Hope it is solution, will try.